# Minimal polynomial of a matrix whose elements have a certain form

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Find the minimal polynomial of the $n$-dimensional matrix $(a_{ij})$ when the matrix elements $a_{ij}$ have the form $a_{ij} = u_i v_j.$

---

Let $A=uv^T$ where $u,v$ are column vectors.

Then rank$(A)\leq$rank$(u)\leq1.$ So kernal$(A)\geq n-1.$ That is, the geometric multiplicity $\geq n-1.$ According to Jordan decomposition theorem, the number of Jordan blocks w.r.t. $0\ \geq n-1.$ Therefore, the algebraic multiplicity of $0$  $\geq n-1.$

Suppose rank$(A)=1,$ how do I find the other eigenvalue?

Comment: If you're missing just one eigenvalue, since the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, ...

Comment: @xavierm02 So the remaining eigenvalue is $<u,v>.$ But how do I get the minimal polynomial from this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the vector $u$ is an eigenvector